# Unable to do a join properly in Ecto/Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a ParentModel, ChildModel1 and ChildModel2. ParentModel has many ChildModel1 and ChildModel1 has many ChildModel2.

```
  data = ChildModel2
         |> join(:left, [chmd2], chmd1 in assoc(chmd2, :child_model1))
         |> where(ChildItem2, [a], a.child_model1.parent_model_id == ^get_some_value()) # get_some_value() returns a number
         |> Repo.all()
```

Here's a exception:

```
cannot use ^get_some_value() outside of match clauses
```

When I replace it with a literal,

```
    |> where(ChildItem2, [a], a.child_model1.parent_model_id == 123)
```

I get:

```
undefined function where/4
```

**update**

The error remains:

```
data = ChildModel2
         |> join(:left, [chmd2], chmd1 in assoc(chmd2, :child_model1))
         |> where([a], a.child_model1.parent_model_id == 123) # [a] is ChildModel2
         |> Repo.all()
```

error:

```
a.child_model1().parent_model_id() is not a valid query expression
```

Comment: Do you have `import Ecto.Query` in this module? You'll get that "cannot use ^ outside ..." error if the macro isn't imported in that module.

Comment: For the second error, I guess you want `|> where([chmd2, chmd1], chmd1.parent_model_id == 123)`.

Comment: @Dogbert, using pin operator won't work with function call.

Comment: @PatNowak `Ecto.Query.where` is a macro. (Did you mean something else?)

Comment: Yeah, I wrote a comment to yours that even if macro is loaded pin operator won't work there with function call `get_some_value()`. Now the question is edited, so it's not bothering @Torito anymore, but is primary issue still remains.

Comment: @PatNowak why wouldn't it work with pin operator? `User |> where([u], u.name == ^String.strip(" foo "))` works for me. It works as long as you don't pass a database field to the function.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation. I tried with case and cond in IEx with anonymous function and it didn't work.

Comment: @Dogbert, `Do you have import Ecto.Query` -- yes.

Comment: @Dogbert, are you sure it's allowed to query by a parent model in "where" ---> `a.child_model1.parent_model_id == 123`?

Comment: @Torito no, that wouldn't work, but something like this should: `|> where([chmd2, chmd1], chmd1.parent_model_id == 123)` assuming you do the `|> join(:left, [chmd2], chmd1 in assoc(chmd2, :child_model1))` before this `where`.

Comment: @Dogbert, thanks, but I've not been able to make it work like that either.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't inject `ChildItem2` in `where`, because it's already passed as the first argument as a result of `join`.

The issue is caused by the `^` (pin operator) and it never works when it's attached to the function call - even in `case` or `cond`. Try to simply assign result of `get_some_value()` to the variable.

Comment: `The issue is caused by the ^ (pin operator) and it never works when it's attached to the function call - even in case or cond` -- it does, I've had it so far in a slightly different query and it's worked well.

Comment: I've replaced `get_some_value()` with  a literal. The error remains:  `a.child_model1().parent_model_id()` is not a valid query expression.

Comment: Are you sure that you properly added this association? `child_model1` and `parent_model_id` are fields, not functions. Did you added field for `child_model1` in schema and migration? Remember also that `assoc` doesn't guarantee that the association is loaded.

Comment: Did you remove from `where` this `childItem`?

Comment: are you sure it's allowed to query by a parent model in "where"?